# Image cannot be resized

Tags: html, css

I have an image within a container that needs to be down scaled. When rendered out the full source code is as below.

```css
/*STAFF LOGIN*/

#myMainContainer {
  border: 10px solid red;
}

#logoStaffLoginPage {
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- Bootstrap css-->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=/static/main.css>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href=/static/style.css>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/static/media/favicon.png" />
  <title></title>

  <!--font-awesome including icon for shopping cart-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <!--Font awesome-->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/efc09bd617.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!--Google recaptcha-->
  <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/enterprise.js?render=6LdNCXEhAAAAAHy7vvB9oqTF8zSfVrGDIfr-82Re"></script>


  <!--Google analytics-->
  <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
  <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-20BMMNWM05"></script>
  <script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

    function gtag() {
      dataLayer.push(arguments);
    }
    gtag('js', new Date());
    gtag('config', 'G-20BMMNWM05');
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container" id="myMainContainer">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <img src="/media/logoWithText.png" alt="Logo" id="logoStaffLoginPage">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col bodyTextBold centerText">
        Staff Login
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <form method="post" action="/accounts/login/">
      <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="V3d7Hqf3vYG8whYv6xF7yU0Cak3dKk21xn7U6X6dxCXEPdHAWd9URA8Sc69YRlOy">
      <label for="id_username">Username:</label>
      <br>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" autofocus autocapitalize="none" autocomplete="username" maxlength="150" required id="id_username">
      <br><br>
      <label for="id_password">Password:</label>
      <br>
      <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" autocomplete="current-password" required id="id_password">
      <br>
      <br>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
    </form>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

I have tried with `max-width` and `max-height` in css and none of them seem to work. Also I have tried to put the `img` out of the container, and even outside it does not scale properly. Also I have tried clear the cookies, and still I am unable to scale down the image.

Below is a screen dump of the page, and I want to down scale the logo image.
[image]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I figured it out. I was edit the wrong css file.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be jquery file missing.  jquery can help to support with the responsive website design need which allow you to set the size condition of your file based on the window size limitation.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can try changing the size of parent container. and use object fit property for logo. The logo image inside will scale itself according to it.
Reference: [https://www.delftstack.com/howto/css/resize-image-css/#:~:text=Use%20the%20object%2Dfit%20Property%20to%20Resize%20the%20Image%20in%20CSS,-We%20can%20use&text=We%20can%20specify%20the%20way,given%20dimension%20of%20the%20container](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/css/resize-image-css/#:%7E:text=Use%20the%20object%2Dfit%20Property%20to%20Resize%20the%20Image%20in%20CSS,-We%20can%20use&text=We%20can%20specify%20the%20way,given%20dimension%20of%20the%20container).

```css
parent-div{
height:200px;
width:300px;
}
image{
height:100%;
width:100%;
object-fit:contain;
}
```